# Iterating over sub-matrices in 2d NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, heightmap

On a floating-point height map from an image I am iterating over each 2x2 square sub-matrix within the array, performing a calculation, summing results. This is slow because elevation maps are large (16K x 16K) and a loop is slower than NumPy or SciPy. How to iterate over blocks of multidimensional NumPy arrays?

This 3x3 NumPy array could be NxM:

```
[[0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
 [3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
 [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]]
```

I want a fast iterator that yields:

```
> [0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
> [1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0]
> [3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 7.0]
> [4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

Order of values within sub-matrix is not important so long as they are consistent (counter-clockwise, clockwise, zig-zag, etc.). My code does not use NumPy:

```
shape_dem_data = shape_dem.getdata() # shape_dem is a PIL image

for x in range(width - 1):
    for y in range(height - 1):
        i = y * width + x
        z1 = shape_dem_data[i]
        z2 = shape_dem_data[i + 1]
        z3 = shape_dem_data[i + width + 1]
        z4 = shape_dem_data[i + width]
        # Create a bit-mask indicating the available elevation data
        mask = (z1 != NULL_HEIGHT) << 3 |\
               (z2 != NULL_HEIGHT) << 2 |\
               (z3 != NULL_HEIGHT) << 1 |\
               (z4 != NULL_HEIGHT) << 0
        if mask == 0b1111:
            # All data available.
            surface_area += area_of_triangle(((0, 0, z1), (gsd, 0, z2), (gsd, gsd, z3)))
            surface_area += area_of_triangle(((0, 0, z1), (gsd, gsd, z3), (0, gsd, z4)))
            pass
        elif mask == 0b1101:
            # Top left triangle
            surface_area += area_of_triangle(((0, 0, z1), (gsd, 0, z2), (0, gsd, z4)))
        elif mask == 0b0111:
            # Bottom right triangle
            surface_area += area_of_triangle(((gsd, 0, z2), (gsd, gsd, z3), (0, gsd, z4)))
        elif mask == 0b1011:
            # Bottom left triangle
            surface_area += area_of_triangle(((0, 0, z1), (gsd, gsd, z3), (0, gsd, z4)))
        elif mask == 0b1110:
            # Top right triangle
            surface_area += area_of_triangle(((0, 0, z1), (gsd, 0, z2), (gsd, gsd, z3)))
return surface_area
```

Purpose is to calculate surface area of an array of heights (given a fixed sampling distance between pixels). The bit-masking checks what combination of pixels are not "null" heights (and adjusts calculation accordingly).

Comment: Look into convolutions, I'm not sure what you are trying to do here but it is some type of convolution.

Comment: Convolution would be very useful depending on your end goal

Comment: Convolution is not really possible in this case because the problem cannot be solved with a simple fixed convolution window.

Comment: Maybe you could investigate the code of landlab for a similar operation? It's a landscape evolution model written in python. This is just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using scikit-image's [`view_as_windows`](http://view_as_windows) is a possible way to go:

```
In [55]: import numpy as np

In [56]: from skimage.util import view_as_windows

In [57]: wrows, wcols = 2, 2

In [58]: img = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3).astype(np.float64)

In [59]: img
Out[59]: 
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.]])

In [60]: view_as_windows(img, window_shape=(wrows, wcols), step=1).reshape(-1, wrows*wcols)
Out[60]: 
array([[0., 1., 3., 4.],
       [1., 2., 4., 5.],
       [3., 4., 6., 7.],
       [4., 5., 7., 8.]])
```

**EDIT**

If the approach above is not valid for you, [`scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter) might do the trick:

```
In [77]: from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter

In [78]: def surface_area(block):
    ...:     z1, z2, z3, z4 = block
    ...:     # YOUR CODE HERE
    ...:     return z1
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [79]: generic_filter(img, function=surface_area, 
    ...:                size=(wrows, wcols), mode='constant', cval=np.nan)
    ...: 
Out[79]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  0.,  1.],
       [nan,  3.,  4.]])
```

Notice that you have to change the function `surface_area` so that it performs the computation correctly (in my toy example it simply returns the upper left value for each 2×2 window).

Comment: While this works, it is actually somehow *significantly* slower than the original implementation.

Comment: @Colin Basnett I'm sorry `view_as_windows` is not fast enough for your application. I've edited my answer to include a second approach that could run faster.