# Looping through n x n matrix with a smaller matrix of certain size with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, sliding-window

I'm currently having the following issue, given an array let's say for simplicity a 4 x 4 array (I'm actually working with 512 x 512 )

```
X = np.array([[3, 5, 2, 4],
              [7, 6, 8, 8],
              [1, 6, 7, 7],
              [2, 1, 3, 4]])
```

I would like to loop/slide around the array in a way that I can save new arrays in the form

`np.array([3,5],[7,6]), np.array([2,4], [8,8]), np.array([1,6],[2,1]), np.array ([7,7],[1,4])` and so on (Ideally that I could choose the step and the size of my "sliding" window). Also I would like to select these arrays according to some conditions , see below.

For the moment I managed to do almost everything by slicing (see code) my matrix. This gives the correct slicing with the step which I want, then by using the `itertools` module I can loop over all my list of lists, count the elements smaller than a certain value and save them. 
What I cannot do is to link the indices between all these new lists together to the main matrix.
For this reason, I was thinking to move everything to `numpy` arrays which should be (in my understanding) much more efficient in terms of computing and I guess should solve my issue of indices. Now the only problem is that I don't know to solve this problem for an arbitrary `n x n` matrix.

```
X = np.array([[3, 5, 2, 4],
          [7, 6, 8, 8],
          [1, 6, 7, 7],
          [2, 1, 3, 4]])

width = len(m[0])
height = len(m)
height = 2  # size of the matrix sliding
width = 2
for i in range(0, height - slice_y + 1,2):
    for j in range(0, width - slice_x + 1,2):

        Appended.append(
                [
                    [m[a][b] for b in range(j, j + slice_x)]
                    for a in range(i, i + slice_y)
                ]

            )
```

Ideally what I would like is for a general matrix N x N but for the moment also only like in the example to get the output as a form of arrays like:

```
np.array([3,5],[7,6]) .  np.array ([2,4], [8,8])  ,  np.array  ([1,6],[2,1]),   np.array ([7,7],[1,4])
```

And let's say once found that e.g the array `np.array([2,4], [8,8])` has two elements bigger than `7` and the sum is more than `20` to save the coordinates of this array with respect of my initial matrix. So saving the indices couples  `X[0][2]`, `X[0][3]`, `X[1][2]`, `X[1][3]` or at least the first `X[0][2]` so by knowing the step of my "window" I can access my subarrays by indexing my main matrix.

Comment: Can the results overlap?

Comment: skimage.util.view_as_windows may be useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009855/iterating-over-square-submatrices-in-multidimensional-numpy-array

Comment: yes in the case of  let's say in the case I wrote one possible solution could be also  np.array([3,5],[7,6]) np.array([5,2],[6,8]) np.array([2,4],[8,8]) and etc

Comment: Indeed view_as_windows may be really useful, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently slice numpy arrays directly

```
X = np.array([[3, 5, 2, 4],
      [7, 6, 8, 8],
      [1, 6, 7, 7],
      [2, 1, 3, 4]])[0:2,0:2]
```

I would in your case generate a list of the indices of the edges of the submatrix you're going to use. Then use that to generate the list of submatricies then use that to generate a list of true or false values based on the submatricies. Then you can use that list of true/false values to prune your initial list of indicies. You could also do this without storing the submatricies at all.

```
indicies= [((i,i+s_width),(j,j+s_height)) for i in range(0,width-s_width) for j in range(0,height-s_height)]
```

Comment: I saw this opportunity in the numpy manual but it's not yet clear if I can loop across all the matrix , let's say I want to slice it with a step of 1 meaning an output like np.array([3,5],[7,6]) np.array([5,2],[6,8]) np.array([2,4],[8,8]) and so on. Or let's imagine a bigger matrix 8x8 where I want to slide with a 2x2 or 4x4 matrix with different steps.     Any help on that ?  Thanks

Comment: So the indicies for the example in your first sentence would be ([0:2],[0:2]),([1:3],[0:2]),([2:4],[0:2]) and so on. On an 8x8 matrix the width and height change.The submatricies are similar.